# How do i set a 410 status for any page with a .html file extension?

Tags: html, .htaccess, http-status-code-410

I had a site which became a victim of some spam hacks. This is all resolved, I am now just trying to set a 410 status for these pages which are part of Google's index. They 404 right now but I want them gone as quick as can be. Thankfully they all used .html and I have no other .html pages in my directory.

How can I use .htaccess to set a 410 to fit the below pattern?

http://domain.com/AnyFileName.html

This should not target anything in a subdirectory, so the below would be ignored:

http://domain.com/folder/AnyFileName.html

Below is what I have tried, but it's still returning a 404.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule \.html$ - [G]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[^/.]+\.html$ - [G,NC,L]
```

`[^/.]+` will make sure to match these html files only in site root leaving html files in sub directories untouched.

Comment: Since the OP's code didn't work, why should this be any different (assuming that the RewriteEngine is set correctly)?

Comment: This is tested and working on my Apache. Do you find anything wrong in this?

Comment: No, I was just asking if there was a reason that this should work *instead* of the OP's code. I believe both should work, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Well OP's code matches all html files not just in site root as OP wants.

Comment: Right, but according to the question, the `.html` files return 404 meaning the rule was not matching the path originally or it was being overridden.

Comment: There can be many reasons for that but I will not speculate rather than verifying the rule on a running Apache.

Comment: Hmm, this works. I don't know why my original solution was not working. I've tested this .htaccess code and it works exactly as what i was looking for.